# Unable to import gensim module

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, gensim, word2vec, topic-modeling

I installed gensim module using (pip install gensim) and it installed successfully

```
Successfully installed boto-2.49.0 boto3-1.12.45 botocore-1.15.45 docutils-0.15.2 gensim-3.8.2 jmespath-0.9.5 s3transfer-0.3.3 smart-open-1.11.1
```

but while importing it on my jupyter notebook, its showing:

```
unable to import 'smart_open.gcs', disabling that module
```

Comment: Is that the full message shown, or was there more info not yet in your question? What exact code triggered that message? What version of Python? Are there any errors when you try later code? (Are you sure that `smart_open.gcs` is necessary for your uses? It looks related to Google Cloud Services, are you using those?)

Comment: 1. this is the full message. 2. this single line of code : (import gensim). 3. (python version 3.7.4) 4. this is the only error i am getting. 5. I am not sure about smart_open.gcs. in command prompt i installed gensim using pip install gensim and smart_open.gcs installed automatically.

Comment: Does this message stop code execution, or is it just informational, with execution proceeding to other code? It may be safe to ignore, unless & until you specifically need any GCS services.

Comment: it disabled the module hence code execution stopped.

Comment: What do you mean by "disabled the module"? (What output/errors give you that impression?) What other code are you intending to run, and what happens (success or error message) when you try to run it? Are you using Google Cloud Services in any way?

Answer (score 2):

This warning can be removed by updating [smart_open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/) to version `2.0.0` or newer.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade smart_open
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively the verion can be downgraded, it just seems to be a problem with version 1.11, so:

```
pip install --upgrade smart-open==1.10.0
```

Information Link for reference: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/issues/475